# SQL Server Agent ignores new job attached to existing schedule -- no errors, no messages, no execution

Tags: sql-server-2019, sql-server-agent

SQL Server: 15.0.4326.1 (2019 Standard Edition, current through CU22 security update )

I have an existing schedule on a SQL Server named Daily0230.  There is one existing job attached to that schedule. Both the schedule and the job are owned by 'sa'.

I attached a brand new job to the existing Daily0230 schedule.  The new job is owned by the SQL Login 'UserLogin'

At 0230, only the existing job started.  The new job did not start.  The SQL Agent logs do not show any errors, and the job history for the new job contains no errors.  The "Next Run" in the Activity Monitor was also unchanged as though the SQL Agent simply ignored it.

The schedule is enabled, and the new job is also enabled.

Has anyone seem similar issues where SQL Agent appears to bypass a scheduled job?

I've gone through several troubleshooting steps and I will be happy to detail them; however, I don't want to bias the discussion by saying, "I think this is the issue"

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: ^or moreso, maybe script out the job and the job schedule and add them to your Post, so we can verify everything appears correct.

Comment: try `select j.name, j.enabled, j.start_step_id, j.owner_sid, js.next_run_date, js.next_run_time from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j join msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules js on js.job_id = j.job_id join msdb.dbo.sysschedules sched on sched.schedule_id = js.schedule_id where sched.name = 'YourScheduleHere'`